# Infinite Scroll Django does not work proprely

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

Note: Intro: I am using this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html to add infinite scroll with django. Just in case anyone wants the detailed code its on Github.It is a very simple code

The Problem: Rather than having infinite scroll I only get more link so it does not work properly

In my static folder. I made a folder called js and added 3 files in it
infinite.min.js, jquery-3.1.1.min.js, jquery.waypoints.min.js
I copied the code exactly from the github in my files

**BELOW IS MY VIEW**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    numbers_list = range(1, 1000)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(numbers_list, 20)
    try:
        numbers = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        numbers = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        numbers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'numbers': numbers})


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

**MY base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


{% load static %}
<html>
<head>


    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">

    {% if title %}
        <title> Django Blog - {{title}} </title>

    {% else %}
        <title> Django Blog </title>

    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Django Blog</a>
          <button class= "navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">About</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}"> Profile</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}"> Logout</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login'  %}">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
</header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                    {{message}}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link pb-2" href="{% url 'post-create' %}"> CREATE A POST!</a>
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>


<script>
  var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
    onBeforePageLoad: function () {
    $('.loading').show();
    },
    onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
    $('.loading').hide();
    }
  });
</script>


  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
  {% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>


**FINALLY MY HOME.HTML** 
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
<script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
    });
</script>


{% block content %}
  <a class="infinite-container">
    {% for post in posts %}
      <article class="media content-section ">
            <img class ="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{post.author.profile.image.url}}">
            <div class="media-body infinite-item">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>

    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% block javascript %}

{% endblock %}


  {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">More</a>
  {% endif %}

{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
{% endif %}

  {% endblock %}
```

Thank you

Comment: welcome to SO, did you check scripts are in the page already ? any console errors shown ?

Comment: Thank you for your welcome ! I checked the scripts but It does not give any error